# handling null in conditional split in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am using the conditional split to split my output.
In conditional split I've used condition

IsNull(Name)

The input to the conditional split is result of left outer join query and it is pass through conditional split and insert into destination.

I came across the situation where the value of Name is not null still it passes through conditional split and insert into destination.

E.g. input has value Name= "/Aav"

Yes in name there is one special character. 
In this Case split condition
IsNull(Name)= False.

Still this value is inserted into destination.
when the conditional slit return true then only it should insert into destination.

Could you please suggest how I can handle this?

Answer (score 0):

check it out it may helps you

[image: only null values of c will come in case1 else will enter in default]

case1 allows only null values of c column

and then case 1 to your destination is what you needed